# Run a query with out a subquery to yield results

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

['MotorVehicles' Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSdSg.png)

I ran a query to find 'AVG(Price) * 2' of attached table, then I ran another query where I substituted 'AVG(Price) * 2' with a hard number, I was able to get the two records in the result table, I have tried to use the aggregate functions in a 'Having' clause but my result table comes back empty. Need some help I would like to formulate a SELECT statement without a subquery to find all Motor vehicles whos price is more or equal to 'AVG(Price * 2)' in attached table.

thanks in advance

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: You need at least two queries to bring the results together.

Comment: Or a window function

Answer (score 0):

Many methods, this isn't nice, but it would work:

```
;with cte_a as
(
    select avg(Price)*2 [Average]
    from yourTable
    -- or whatever your query to get average is as long as only 1 result
)
select *
from yourTable yt
inner join cte_a a on 1 = 1
where price >= a.Average
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from MotorVehicles where price > (select avg(price) from t)*2;
```

I apologise if this is the subquery you want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can get something similar using a partitioned AVG().

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    X INT
)

INSERT @T SELECT 1
INSERT @T SELECT 10
INSERT @T SELECT 15
INSERT @T SELECT 20

SELECT X,XAVG=AVG(X) OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ) FROM @T
```

Resulting in:

```
X   XAVG
1   11
10  11
15  11
20  11
```